# Interesting observation when minimizing the function $nk(1+n^{1/k})$

Tags: calculus, optimization, numerical-methods

I recently ran into the function $nk(1+n^{1/k})$ that I am trying to minimize, given a value of $n.$ Plotting this on desmos (or any more extravagent tests) easily shows that this function only has one local minimum, and taking the first derivative shows that this minimum occurs when $$n^{1/k}(k\log n - 1) = 1.$$

I was unable to solve the above equation for $k$, and so I resorted to numerics. Though the $k$ values obviously varied widely according to $n,$ surprisingly, $\frac 1k\log n $ seemed to be equal to a constant $\approx 1.279$ for all values of $n$ I tried (up to $e^{50}$).

Thus, I have two questions:

1. What is the exact value of this constant?
2. Why is the value of $\frac 1k\log n$ remarkably constant even when $n$ varies largely? Is there any intuition that could have led to predicting this result?

EDIT 1: The exact value of the constant seems to be the solution to $e^{-x}=x-1;$ I am still looking for intuition of why this works.

Comment: Might be interesting: if we put $y=log(n)/k$, and $x=1/k^2$, we have $e^y(y/x-1)=1$. Equivalently $e^{-y}+1=y/x$. If $x$ is roughly $1$, we get your equation.

Comment: Over which variable do you want to minimize, $k$ or $n$, or both? Over what domain do you want to minimize?

Answer (score 2):

Using @Madarb suggestion, considering the equation
$$e^{-y}+1=\frac y x$$ and, for the time being ignoring the relations between $x$ and $y$, we have
$$y=x+W\left(x\,e^{-x} \right)$$ and if $$x\to 1\implies y\to 1+W\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\approx 1.27846$$.